# Display bug on moderation dashboard

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

[image: moderation dashboard]

Why is the text offset left and right? Sathya says it doesn't happen on SU

Because some mods say that they don't quite see what I'm referring to, I enhanced it a tad bit.

[image: Moderation dashboard, #2]

Comment: +1 for FHC, and because I see what you are talking about now. I completely missed that the first time. The black bars just through me off I guess

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if @Jin fixed this or if it just went away in the course of making other changes, but either way, I didn't see this behavior.